# Generic Method for Classes/Values & Dates

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm creating a helper method to assist with the below. Ideally, there would be one signature for this method to make it easier. But can't seem to find the right combination to make it work.

```
StringProp = Get<string>(item, 3);
DateProp = Get<DateTime?>(item, 4);
DateNullProp = Get<DateTime?>(item, 5);

private static T Get<T>(Row item, int index) where T : class
{
    return item[index] as T;
}
```

How can I get this to work? Is it even supported? I made a dedicated method, but would like to avoid it if I can.

The class constraint won't work for dates, but I couldn't find any combination.

Is it possible to have the one method signature for this?

Comment: What are you going to return if `T` is `DateTime`, but `item[index]` id *not* of `DateTime` type? E.g. what is the result of `Get<DateTime>(item, 0)` when `item[0] = "bla-bla-bla"?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the constraint and do the type-check with `is`:

```
static T Get<T>(Row item, int index)
{
    var itemAtIndex = item[index];
    if (itemAtIndex is T val)
    {
        return val;
    }

    return default;
}
```

Or single line:

```
static T Get<T>(Row item, int index) => item[index] is T val ? val : default;
```

Note that for non-nullable value types it will return [default value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values) (for example `DateTime.MinValue` for `DateTime`), if it is not ok in some cases it can be tackled with additional `defaultVal` parameter for the method.

```
static T Get<T>(Row item, int index, T defaultValue = default) 
   => item[index] is T val 
       ? val 
       : defaultValue;
```

See also:

- [Type-testing operators and cast expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast)
- [Pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, `as` doesn't work for `struct` like `DateTime`. You can try switching to `is` and *pattern matching*:

```
private static T Get<T>(Row item, int index, T defaultValue = default)
{
    return item[index] is T result
      ? result
      : defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: This is a better answer; it allows the caller to optionally change the failure behavior